# Android Java определить абсолютный путь выбранного фала

Tags: java, android

В приложении нужно выбрать произвольный файл и отправить его на сервер. Для отправки использую VolleyPlus, поэтому нужен абсолютный путь к файлу.

Вызываю диалог:

```
Intent intent = new Intent()
                        .setType("*/*")
                        .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a file"), FILE_SELECT_RESULT);
```

Обрабатываю выбранное

```
 Uri selectedfile = intent.getData();
```

Но из этого uri не получается вытащить полный путь к файлу. Получается что-то вроде /document/audio:91106. А нормальное название файл другое - например sunny.mp3. 
Как получить нормальный путь к файлу?

П.С.: с картинками было все просто, а вот с файлами запутался.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению код определения полного пути из `Uri` - довольно сложный. Связано это с тем, что `Uri` может возвращаться в виде пути в некоем `ContentProvider`е, которых может быть довольно много типов.

Неполный код, который дает представление об общей логике такой:

```
/**
 * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
 * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
 * other file-based ContentProviders.<br>
 * <br>
 * Callers should check whether the path is local before assuming it
 * represents a local file.
 * 
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @see #isLocal(String)
 * @see #getFile(Context, Uri)
 * @author paulburke
 */
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    if (DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG + " File -",
                "Authority: " + uri.getAuthority() +
                        ", Fragment: " + uri.getFragment() +
                        ", Port: " + uri.getPort() +
                        ", Query: " + uri.getQuery() +
                        ", Scheme: " + uri.getScheme() +
                        ", Host: " + uri.getHost() +
                        ", Segments: " + uri.getPathSegments().toString()
                );

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // LocalStorageProvider
        if (isLocalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            // The path is the id
            return DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
        }
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        else if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Полный код разрешенный относительно мелких функций и методов приведенных в примере [лежит здесь](https://github.com/ivanovpv/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java)

Answer (score 0):

Решение зависит от API level. Здесь библиотека, которая реализует все решения в одном классе.

https://gist.github.com/tatocaster/32aad15f6e0c50311626